# Javascript - Check if 2 items exist in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, how can I ensure that the array of ages has **both** ages `10` and `18` and not just one.

```
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
ages.filter(age => age === 10 || age === 18); // returns 10 and 18
ages.filter(age => age === 10 && age === 18); // returns null
```

The `&&` doesn't ensure that both exist, as it returns `null`. I know I can use 2 different `ages.find/filter` and check the combined result, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this in a single statement.

To clarify, in the `ages` array, if I check for `10` (exists) and `21` (doesn't exist), it should return `null` or `false`, as one of them does not exist.

Comment: `new Set(ages.filter(age => age === 10 || age === 18)).size >= 2`

Comment: See [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I think its best to use 2 different filters since in an iteration, age can just be a single number, either 10 or 18 so if you use &&, one of them will always be false.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek not a duplicate, I am trying to ensure both exist at once, not just one...

Comment: Checking for two is just checking for a single one twice. This is a duplicate in the same way finding element `a` and element `b` is a duplicate for finding element `a`. So other than just `if ( ages.indexOf( 10 ) > -1 )` it's just `if ( ages.indexOf( 10 ) > -1 && ages .indexOf( 18 ) > -1)`. That's why it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `includes` function:

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
console.log(ages.includes(10) && ages.includes(18));
```

Another method is to use `indexOf` method:

> arr.indexOf(searchElement)
>
> arr.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
console.log(ages.indexOf(10)!=-1 && ages.indexOf(18)!=-1);
```

`findIndex` is another method that you can use.It actions like `indexOf`, but there are some differences:

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) expects a value as parameter. This is usefull for arrays of primitive types,such as `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`.

[Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) have a callback function as first parameter. This is usefull specially when you have array of objects.

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
var bool=ages.findIndex(a=>a==10)!=-1 && ages.findIndex(a=>a==18)!=-1;
console.log(bool);
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks for including both ways :)

Comment: instead of using `findIndex() != -1` I'd rather use [some()](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). `ages.some(v => v === 10) && ages.some(v => v === 18)`

Comment: Thanks for your point ! You can include sugestion inside my answer if you wish.Good point.